# Java: Plotting points uniformly on a circle using Graphics2d

Tags: java, trigonometry, graphics2d

I'm trying to draw a number of points on a circle such that each point is the same distance from the next. Eventually I'll be drawing lines between all of the points to make a little drawing. The current hurdle I am dealing with is the points don't come out on the circle uniformly. The way I am figuring the points is, for a given point with angle theta, the X coordinate and Y coordinate are calculated as follows

xc = radius * (Math.cos(theta)) + horizontal center

yc = radius * (Math.sin(theta)) + vertical center

I also have an extra variable so I can make a spinning animation. Here is the code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;


    class JavaPaintUI extends JPanel{
        int x,y,rad,i;
        static Random r = new Random();
        BufferedImage image;
        Graphics2D g2d;
        Timer timer;
        double vertices = 24.0;
        double angle = 0.0;
        double delta = 0.01;
        double [] xs = new double[24];
        double [] ys = new double[24];

        JavaPaintUI(){
            image = new BufferedImage(600, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            g2d = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
            setBackground(Color.black);
            g2d.setColor(Color.white);
            i=0;
            ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    angle += delta;
                    angle = angle % 360.0;
                    iterate();
                }
            };
            timer = new Timer(100, listener);
            timer.start();
        }
        public void iterate(){
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);


            for(double i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
                xs[(int)i] = 250.0 * (Math.cos(((2*Math.PI)/360) * (angle+(i*(360.0/vertices))))) + 300.0;
                ys[(int)i] = 250.0 * (Math.sin(((2*Math.PI)/360) * (angle+(i*(360.0/vertices))))) + 300.0;
            }

            for(double i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
                g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(xs[(int)i], ys[(int)i], 8.0, 8.0));
            }

            /*
            for(double i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
                for(double j = 0; j < vertices; j++){
                    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(xs[(int)i],ys[(int)i],xs[(int)j],ys[(int)j]));
                }
            } */

            repaint();    
            if (i==1000){timer.stop();}
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
            }
        }
```

I used code from another stack overflow post.Here is a picture of what the circle looks like as of now.

[image: circle]

As you can see, there are some extra space between some of the points. Does anyone know what causes this?

EDIT

Thanks guys! It looks much better!

[image: circle2]

Comment: dont forget to upvote the usefull answers (arrow up)

Comment: Glad we could help. Looks cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the trig functions in `Math` take their parameters in radians, not degrees. So you need to do `2 * Math.PI` instead of `360.0`.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` take an angle in radians and you are providing angles in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

A circle has 360 degrees.
So you need an

```
int numSteps = 32;
double angleStep = 360 / numStpes;   // You also can do that with 2*Math.PI / numSteps

for (int i = 0; i < numSteps; i++) {
   double angle = i * anglStep;
   // now use the formula with x0 + r * sin(angle * toRadians);

}
```

Comment: Ah I had that 360/vertices but I didn't have it in radians. I thought degrees would work but apparently not. Thanks!