# Plotting Points on Circle

Tags: java, rotation, trigonometry

I was playing around in java and was trying to create my own version of the point class:

```
public class Location {
    public double x, y;

    public Location(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double dist(Location location) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(location.x - x, 2) + Math.pow(location.y - y, 2));
    }

    //Rotates the point the amount in angle around the point center
    public void rotate(Location center, double angle) {
        //Also tried this
        /*double current = Math.atan2(center.y - y, center.x - x);
        x = center.x + (Math.cos(current + angle) * dist(center));
        y = center.y + (Math.sin(current + angle) * dist(center));*/
        //Current code
        x = center.x + (Math.cos(angle) * dist(center));
        y = center.y + (Math.sin(angle) * dist(center));
    }
}
```

However, no matter what I try, the data returned by the `rotate()` function is slightly off. Instead of a perfect circle, this function outputs a strange deflated shape.

```
public class Circle {

    //Should output circle
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            Location point = new Location(100, 100);
            point.rotate(new Location(200, 200), Math.toRadians(i * 20));
            System.out.print("(" + point.x + ", " + point.y + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

When I outputted these coordinates to [this plotting site](http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/activities/SimplePlot/) this is the image I get:[image: Weird shape that isn't a circle]

My math is identical to [Java: Plotting points uniformly on a circle using Graphics2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179240/java-plotting-points-uniformly-on-a-circle-using-graphics2d) so I don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate `dist(center)` once, store it in a variable, then use that variable in updating `x` and `y`:

```
double d = dist(center);
x = center.x + (Math.cos(angle) * d);
y = center.y + (Math.sin(angle) * d);
```

`dist(center)` depends upon `x`, so you get a different value after updating `x` when calculating the new value of `y`.